# Docker compose can't find named Dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

my project structure is defined like this (names are just for example):

```
- docker-compose.yml
- env_files
  - foo.env
- dockerfiles
  -service_1
    -foo.Dockerfile
    -requirements.txt
- code_folder_1
  - ...
- code_folder_2
  - ...
```

In my docker-compose:

```
some_service:
    container_name: foo_name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/service_1/foo.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    env_file:
      - ./env_files/foo.env
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /some_work_dir
COPY ./dockerfiles/intermediary/requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==21.3.1 && \
   pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 80
```

And after i run  `docker compose build` in the directory where compose file is located I get this error:

```
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount4158855397/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I really do not understand why this is happening. I need to set `context:.` because I have multiple folders that I need to COPY inside foo.Dockerfile

Same error was replicated in macOS Monterey 12.5.1 and Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: Can you please execute - `docker-compose config` and check How it looks for your service. Right now I can see that it is not considering the argument `dockerfile` and hence look for default file name (Dockerfile)

Comment: @fly2matrix 
    `build:
      context: /Users/<user_name>/Desktop/folder_on_desktop/project_name_where_compose_is_located
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/service_1/foo.Dockerfile`


**FULL PATH to DOCKERFILE:**
 `/Users/<user_name>/Desktop/folder_on_desktop/project_name_where_compose_is_located/dockerfiles/service_1/foo.Dockerfile`